# A correct word for 'learnful'

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for a word that would fit in the sentence *it was a very **learnful** experience*: i.e., I learned a lot during that experience.

*Learnful* feels correct to me, but the dictionary disagrees. It’s possible I’'m incorrectly assuming there is an English equivalent to the Dutch word *leerzaam*, but I can’t imagine there is no word to convey such a meaning.

Google Translate suggests *instructive* or *informative*, but those seem to either mean providing ways of doing things or factual information. What I want it to mean is more abstract, including things like skills and insights and overall growth in competency.

---

Interestingly, I do now think that the Dutch word *leerzaam* might not be translatable to English after all; so if someone (Dutch) has some thoughts on this, it might be of interest, since the languages are so similar.

I’m trying to think of a nice counterexample, but the best I can come up with now is this:

> Although it was a setback that my roof collapsed, it was an educational experience, and I would never start a home improvement project without proper preparation again.

That does sound pretty awkward in English, right?

Comment: Response to edit 2: no, that actually sounds perfectly natural. People say things like that all the time.

Comment: Knowledgeable experience?

Comment: According to Wiktionary, in "leerzam", the "-zaam" suffix shares an origin with the English suffix "-some", as in "fearsome", while "leer" shares its origin with the English word "lore". So the pieces do both exist in English, as does the concept, but the specific word doesn't seem to.

Comment: `a learning experience` suits you example sentence perfectly.

Comment: [**learningful**](https://www.google.it/search?q=learningful&oq=learningful&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=learningful&tbm=bks) is used and heard often enough. It's in Google Books, around  868 results.

Comment: @Mari-LouA 868? That's nothing. Even "logorrhea" has 11,500 results. I've never encountered the word "learningful" until your comment.

Comment: That example sounds fine. I would expect people to say it a bit more concisely: "Although it was a setback when my roof collapsed, it was educational, and I'll never start a home improvement project without properly preparing again."

Comment: "Learnful" sounds like a playful neologism - I would know what the speaker meant. But "educational" is probably the more conventional choice.

Comment: how about 'insightful'?

Comment: ...it was an experience I learned from/to learn from?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments this was very instructive. 
@Mari-LouA, Kyle Strand: the link you reference from Google Books containing the word _learningful_ seem to be mostly written by authors with foreign sounding names, or contain quotes around it, so it makes it sense that a lot if it comes from other non-native speakers that made the same mistake as me.

Comment: Dutch "leerzaam" has quite a positive feel-good connotation. "Learning experience" in non-academic English is often gently ironic, implying learning from a bad experience. In both languages, "educational" and "informative" are rather dry synonyms, lacking emotional feel. I think you are right to conclude that there is no direct translation.

Comment: @ThomasBosman Don't you mean that all the comments were very learnful? ;-)

Comment: Edifying would be the best I believe. Didactic even.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your original sentence "It was a very learnful experience" would normally be phrased "The experience was very educational" or "It was a very instructive/informative experience"

Educate, inform, instruct, teach, have similar meanings and can be substituted for leerzaam when translating to English.  Instructive is likely the one that best fits your intention.  The context of the sentence would clarify what was learned.

Leerzaam in English would be educational, informative, instructive.

Instructief and informatief in fact are given as Dutch synonyms for leerzaam

As so often happens, the word does not have an exact counterpart in English, but rather a short list of words with similar meanings that cover various specific uses of the word being translated.

Comment: +1 for the "The experience was very educational", because changing the sentence structure is actually quite a good idea in general when you stuck on finding the correct translation, which I really didn't think of.

Comment: "insightful" too, depending where on the scale 'learnful' was intended to fall.

Answer (score 34):

The term [instructive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/instructive) can be used in the sentence:

> - Conveying knowledge or information; enlightening.(AHD)

or [educational](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/educational):

> - Serving to educate; instructive: an educational film.(AHD)

Comment: Due to the questioner's comment, "What I want it to mean is more abstract, including things like skills and insights and overall growth in competency," I was going to submit **enlightening**, but here you already have enlightening in the definition for instructive.

Answer (score 21):

It was a very *edifying* experience.

> Edifying:  **adjective** Providing moral or intellectual instruction

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/edifying)

Comment: I think 'edifying' is much more strongly associated with moral instruction than it is with intellectual instruction. But that's just my $0.02.

Comment: Edifying is spot on. As a native of the UK, I would use it in exactly the context given: "It was an edifying experience"

Answer (score 15):

It's simple, but also a good fit for what you're trying to convey:

> **educational**
>
> providing knowledge; instructive or informative

*Source: Dictionary.com - British Dictionary*

"Informative" could also work:

> **informative**
>
> giving information; instructive

*Source: Dictionary.com*

Answer (score 8):

**It was a learning experience** seems idiomatic

[Google books](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22it%20was%20a%20learning%20experience%22)

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%20was%20a%20learning%20experience&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20a%20learning%20experience%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: No. A "learning experience" is one in which you have made a mistake and grasped its significance.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus: It's used in that sense a lot, but not _exclusively_. [See top results here](https://www.google.com/search?q=learning+experience&oq=learning+experience&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). Anyway, I appreciate you having the decency and balls to explain your downvote. Wish more people were like that

Comment: +1 @WinnieNicklaus I agree that a learning experience usually involves mistakes. How does that make this not correct?

Comment: Based on the OP's phrase "things like skills and insights and overall growth in competency", the question seemed more directed to moments of deliberate instruction. The example in edit #2, however (which I missed at first reading), does point to learning from a mistake, and in that case I agree that "learning experience" is most idiomatic.

Comment: @TusharRaj +1 my distinguished UK colleague, a perfect english man and who wrote many times in Don's Diary (The Times) used this expression ("a learning experience") to describe an improvement of skills and insights and overall growth in competency, so I like it !

Comment: Interesting. I suggest that this is an example where google has neatly captured the written, *academic*, usage to the exclusion of the spoken and vernacular. Nearly all the examples from ngram are academic texts. All the top hits on the google results are from professional pedagogic institutions. http://edglossary.org/learning-experience suggests that the growth of the phrase is a deliberate innovation to fill a gap in the technical vocabulary needed by the education profession. 

The idiomatic meaning is more negative (e.g. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/learning+experience)

Answer (score 5):

While Josh61 already mentioned it in the *definition* of "instructive" (and Digital Chris refrained from posting it as an answer), I think

**englightening**

best fits all the use cases you described, especially the gain of greater insight even from negative input.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/enlighten?q=enlightening)

Comment: I think "enlightening" is an excellent suggestion. Most of the other suggestions (e.g., "educational") tend to emphasize knowledge being transmitted. "Enlightening" puts the emphasis as (I perceive) it was in the original, on the receipt of the knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Valuable.  If the experience taught you something, or several things, it was a very valuable experience.

It was a valuable experience.  I learned x, y, and z.

Comment: An educational experience would probably be valuable, but valuable is too vague to express the desired meaning.

Answer (score 2):

**Eye-opener** - [**M-W**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/162061/nagarajan-shanmuganathan?tab=profile)

> Something that shows or teaches you something in a surprising way.

Ex: Living in another country can be a real eye-opener.

**Cambridge dictionary** defines [**eye-opener**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eye-opener) as

> Something that surprises you and teaches you new facts about life, people, etc

Answer (score 0):

“It was a real learning experience.”  - “real” here is not used to mean “factual”, but as an intensive, as in “That soup is real hot.”

Comment: @MilesRout: Simmer down, amigo. I learned from Shakespeare, who taught us that there aren't any two words that can't be placed next to one another.

Comment: @MilesRout: “how English works” sounds pretty descriptivist to me. Anyway, if  you’re done dealing from the bottom of the deck, I’ll be happy to have the community decide which of us has pinned the tail on the donkey.